# Receive GPS with 2 antennas

Tags: rf, gps

For an amateur rocket project, I want to receive the GPS signal from 2 antennas placed in the opposite directions, but I'm very beginner in RF domain.

So my first thought is to use a signal Power Splitter and an LNA (like LaNA from NoonELEC) to re-boost the power lost from the Power splitter and feed-up a Neo8N GPS Receiver.

Am I missing something in my design? or should I consider using 2 GPS receiver each use its own antenna and then merge the 2 outputs in software.

Comment: also note that GPS receivers **must** shut themselves off when they detect they travel at rocket-typical speeds or heights!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not aware of such limitation, is that a security/safety guard built-in requirement in GPS receivers?

Comment: yes; that's required by law (it's complicated, but basically: if your GPS can guide a rocket, you can only sell your GPS modules to NATO partner defense industry after applying for a license to do so and mustn't make it publicly available)

Comment: at what maximum speeds and altitudes your GPS receiver works: check with the data sheet, and / or with ublox! They're really a helpful bunch.

Comment: You CAN buy GPS receivers without the height or speed (about Mach 2) limitations; but you'll have to jump through all sorts of export paperwork hoops to get them, and probably for amateur rocketry it'll be completely impossible.

Comment: @MarcusMüller your concern may not apply at all to most model rocketry. I believe the limitations kick in above 59,000 feet (18,000 m) and 1200 mph (1900 km/h). If the rocket can stay within those operating parameters the GPS should function OK.

Comment: Might be able to use 2 antennas with an electronic switch. I guess you can use one antenna during ascent, and another one after apogee. So assuming you can detect apogee, then switch, it should be possible.

Comment: @mkeith you're right. Our rocket maximal speed will be around 980km/h (0.80 mach), we are not allowed to reach 1mach due some safety limitation imposed by local regulatory.

Answer (score 1):

If your GPS doesn't natively support 2 antennas (take a look a diversity antenna) than the RF project is really complicated and expensive.

Consider, as you said, 2 GPS receivers.

Comment: Unfortunately Neo8N does not support diversity antenna :-( Sure, I'll certainly go for 2 GPS receivers. But I want to have good understanding on what makes this project so complicated ..

Comment: @Zskdan, Re, "what makes this...so complicated?" TLDR: If you connect two antennas to each other, then you no longer have two antennas. You now have one [_array antenna_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_array) which, if it was not purposely and carefully designed, may not do anything like what you expected it to do.

Comment: @Zskdan If it doesn't support diversity then you are unlikely to improve anything with two antennas, but likely to make the signal worse.

Answer (score 0):

Without RF measuring tools, or antenna experience, you might try something *really simple* first, to see if it meets your needs. Such a simple approach works adequately for ballooning GPS. A dead-simple antenna is shown below:
[image: simple GPS antenna]

It can be constructed with magnet-wire, and has a reasonably wide bandwidth making cutting lengths not-too-critical.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but unfortunately this cannot work for me because the rocket core is a carbon fiber (conductive) tube with a 20cm diameter but the 1/2 wavelength of the GPS signal is ~= 10 cm. Although I'll keep this for other rocket mechanical design.

Comment: If the core is carbon fiber, maybe you can put a slot antenna in the wall of the core. I think some slot antennas are nearly omnidirectional. This is just a speculation. Not at all sure it will work.